# Looking for Java 7 native agent demos, for use specifically on Mac or Linux

Tags: java, native, agents

I use to work with Java native agents years ago, and I'm getting back to this. I was wondering....what happened to them?

There were examples in jdk1.6/demo/jvmti directory, but with Java 7, there doesn't seem to be a demo directory. What happened to them?

Anyways, I found the 1.6 demo's (on windows) and I'm trying to compile them on linux and mac using jdk 1.6. There is no sample makefile example for the mac, so that is the one I need the most help with. Is there any way to compile the native agents using jdk 1.6? How about jdk 1.7?

On linux, I somehow got the agents to compile with jdk 1.6, but the ones that depend on the java_crw_demo code doesn't seem to work. I think I may have compiled them wrongly.

The demo's in question are:

- agent_util
- gctest
- heapTracker
- heapViewer
- hprof
- java_crw_demo
- minst
- mtrace
- versionCheck
- waiters

Anyways, a google search about agents seems to imply that the agents are still being used with jdk 1.7, but there doesn't seem to be the example support that there once was. Is Oracle trying to limit (or sunset) agents?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you be a bit more clear about what specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to compile the src's from the 1.6 demo's that I have, but while successful, I'm not sure why they fail at runtime. The demo's I compiled long ago (maybe they were already compiled) seem to work on windows. What I would really want is to successfully compile the demo's on linux and mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVMTI demos may or may not come bundled with your JDK installation, depending on where you get it from. They are absent (afaict) from OpenJDK installs. But in any case the demos are still available in all cases from the [Oracle Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). Download the [tarball for Mac](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02-demos/jdk-7u17-macosx-x86_64-demos.tar.gz), expand it to a directory and then browse it.

In relative folder `jdk1.7.0_10/demo/jvmti` you will find the following demos:

> drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 compiledMethodLoad
>   drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 gctest
>   drwxr-xr-x@  6 tuoyo  staff    204 Nov 29 19:30 heapTracker
>   drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 heapViewer
>   drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 hprof
>   drwxr-xr-x@  6 tuoyo  staff    204 Nov 29 19:30 minst
>   drwxr-xr-x@  6 tuoyo  staff    204 Nov 29 19:30 mtrace
>   drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 versionCheck
>   drwxr-xr-x@  5 tuoyo  staff    170 Nov 29 19:30 waiters

Each individual demo has a source ZIP file with code and a sample makefile. You will more than likely need to tweak the makefile to get the build to work on your target system.

On a side note, you may want to look at the [Java Instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), as it wraps JVMTI and provides a more convenient interface over it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for the link. I will try them out. These demo's look a little different than the 1.6 demo's. There is no java_crw_demo directory, but I see that they include the src for that in at least heapTracker. I'll try to compile these. Though, I see that at least for heapTracker, it already seems to be compiled. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I see that the download page also has the mac downloads, too. Thanks, a lot! :-)